# Connect business one drive folder to Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to connect one drive sub folder with power bi desktop through SharePoint Folder.

But i am getting error

Details: "Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed:

OData Version: 3 and 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found)

OData Version: 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found)

OData Version: 3, Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. (Not Found)"

I appreciate your Support.

Thanks.